# STM32 HAL Using ADC with DMA affects UART transmission

Tags: adc, stm32, uart, dma

I am using STM32 Nucleo F334R8 board. I transmit some data using UART in asynchronous mode to my PC using:

```
HAL_UART_Transmit_IT(&huart2, &data, sizeof(data));
```

I noticed that after enabling ADC in DMA mode microcontroller started to send incorrect data over UART.

When I just only commented out:

```
HAL_ADC_Start_DMA(&hadc1, adc_dma_values, 2);
```

UART transmission sends correct data.

When I replaced `HAL_UART_Transmit_IT()` with `HAL_UART_Transmit()` it also surprisingly works well.

I do not understand how `HAL_ADC_Start_DMA()` may affect `HAL_UART_Transmit_IT()`.

Here's whole code of [main.c](https://pastebin.com/Mh3brtDE), maybe it would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the followings:

- the UART is working if you are using it without interrupts along with the DMA, and
- if DMA is not used the UART works with interrupts.

The DMA interrupts possibly happens so often that it do not let the UART IRQ to be executed as the CPU is always busy to handle DMA interrupts.

Giving higher priority to UART IRQ should solve the issue.

Comment: You are perfectly right. That was my problem. I changed priorities of interrupts and now works well. Thank you!